# Mount a raw partition over network

Tags: linux, mount, partition

I need to mount a `ntfs` partition that sits on Linux raid6, so I can run `chkdsk` on it on a Windows machine. I ran `ntfsfix` on Linux already and it showed no errors, but I'm sure there's an error since a file that's supposed to be 100GB shows size as 0.

```
$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/md0p1
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/md0p1 was processed successfully.
```

I'm thinking of mounting this partition over the network so I can access it using a windows machine, how will I do that?

Comment: Even if you can it won't work for your intended purpose of running error correction tools. Those tools are only for local drives.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Think I got this working once but I forgot how.

Comment: iSCSI makes raw devices available over the network, should work both on linux and windows.

Comment: @dirkt Still Windows error correction tool cannot be used in network shares.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia: it's not a network share (and that would be Samba on Linux). Read up on iSCSI, then you'll understand why a Windows error correction tool *will* work over the network.